# Using grepl() to remove values from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a `data.frame` with 1 column, and a nondescript number of rows.

This column contains strings, and some strings contain a substring, let's say `"abcd"`.

I want to remove any strings from the database that contain that substring. For example, I may have five strings that are `"123 abcd"`, and I want those to be removed.

I am currently using `grepl()` to try and remove these values, but it is not working. I am trying:

```
data.frame[!grepl("abcd", dataframe)]
```

but it returns an empty data frame.

Comment: Share reproducible data. Here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grepl` to get a logical vector, negate (`!`) it, and use that to subset the 'data'

```
data[!grepl("abcd", data$Col),,drop = FALSE]
```